# Monitoring health of logstash

Tags: ruby, jvm, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am going to be using logstash to send a high amount of events to a broker. I have monitoring of the broker to check the health status, but I can't find much information on how to see if the logstash process is healthy, if there are indicators of a failing process.

I was interested for those who use logstash, what are some ways you monitor it?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a cronjob inject a heartbeat message and route such messages to some kind of monitoring system. If you already use Elasticsearch you could use it for this as well and write a script to ensure that you have reasonably recent heartbeat messages from all hosts that should be sending messages, but I'd prefer using e.g. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [lovebeat-go](https://github.com/boivie/lovebeat-go).

This could be used to monitor the health of a single Logstash instance (i.e. you inject the heartbeat message into the same instance that feeds the monitoring software) but you could just as well use it to check the overall health of the whole pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This got built into Logstash in 2015. See [the announcement of the Logstash heartbeat plugin](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-check-logstashs-pulse).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to monitor logstash as a shipper, it's easy to write a script that would compare the contents of the .sincedb* file to the actual file on disk to make sure they're in sync.

As an indexer, I'd probably skip ahead and query ElasticSearch for the number of documents being inserted.

@magnus' idea for a latency check is also good.  I've used the log's timestamp and compared it to ElasticSearch's timestamp to compute the latency.

Comment: Which Elasticsearch timestamp?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  Logstash records the timestamp when the log entry was received (@timestamp).  Elasticsearch just stores what Logstash tells it to.  The gap between the two is still useful.